# Export some specific tables as file by converting gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, android-room

I'm trying to export two of my room tables into phono's directory. The way I figured out is that I convert two of my tables using `Gson` and save it into local directory. But the problems is I don't know how to combine that 2 converted `JSON`-s into one.

My codes:

```
   //for first class
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> objStrings1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Clas1 data: datas_1){
        objStrings.add(gson.toJson(data));
    }
    saveLocal(objStrings1)

    //for second class
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> objStrings2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Clas2 data: datas_2){
        objStrings.add(gson.toJson(data));
    }
    saveLocal(objStrings2)
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: I'm asking for suggestion. With this way I do not get any error but it creates 2 different files. I'm asking how can I combine them into one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one root `Pojo` and bind these two list in one class. Also, it will be faster than generating `JSON` for each instance and concatenate it later. See below example which shows the idea:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class1> class1s = Arrays.asList(new Class1(), new Class1(), new Class1());
        List<Class2> class2s = Arrays.asList(new Class2(), new Class2(), new Class2());

        Pojo root = new Pojo();
        root.setClass1s(class1s);
        root.setClass2s(class2s);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        String json = gson.toJson(root);
        System.out.println(json);

        Pojo deserialised = gson.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(deserialised);
    }
}

class Pojo {

    private List<Class1> class1s;
    private List<Class2> class2s;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Class1 {

    private int id = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Class2 {

    private int age = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(70);
    private String name = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5);

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "class1s": [
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "class2s": [
    {
      "age": 12,
      "name": "qXcaT"
    },
    {
      "age": 33,
      "name": "3wXv4"
    },
    {
      "age": 18,
      "name": "55XZ6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Pojos:

```
Pojo{class1s=[Class1{id=2}, Class1{id=1}, Class1{id=3}], class2s=[Class2{age=12, name='qXcaT'}, Class2{age=33, name='3wXv4'}, Class2{age=18, name='55XZ6'}]}
```